# How to know which submit button is being clicked?

Tags: forms, cakephp

I have this two buttons,

```
<?php echo (($active_players >= 25 && !$active_players_check_bypass) ? $html->submit('Submit Registration', array('onclick'=>'return window.confirm("You have reached your maximum allowable players per team. In order to register this player, you must pay the $25.00 required overage fee in order to continue. Do you wish to continue with the registration?")')) : $html->submit('Submit Registration'));
  echo $html->submit('Register Player using Registration Credits', array('id'=>'submitregistrationusingcredits')); // this will use the credits of the team
?>
```

The first button is `Submit Registration` and the other is `Register Player using Registration Credits`, now is there a way to know which button I clicked? Im using `CakePHP` and I am very new to this, is there a way to know which button I clicked so that when validating the form in my controller I will be able to tell what button I clicked and have a process which belongs to each button? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to put a name / value on the button? It should appear in the $data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not intimately familiar with CakePHP's HTMl or Form Helper (or whatever you're using there).  However I think if you add a name parameter in the second array argument:

```
$html->submit('Register Player using Registration Credits', array('name' => 'usingCredits', 'id' => 'submitregistrationusingcredits'));
```

Do that for both submit buttons.  Then when you are handling that request you can write some code that will look like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['usingCredits'])) 
{
    // handle submission using credits
} 
else
{
    // handle another submission method
}
```

You probably want to specify a name for both and check that each name is set.  But that's the idea.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I didn't mention that $_POST was just a placeholder for however you get the form submitted data,  CakePHP may have some other way too...

Answer (score 1):

Set the name attribute on each submit button.

```
echo (($active_players >= 25 && !$active_players_check_bypass) ? $html->submit('Submit Registration', array('name'=>'submit1a', 'onclick'=>'return window.confirm("You have reached your maximum allowable players per team. In order to register this player, you must pay the $25.00 required overage fee in order to continue. Do you wish to continue with the registration?")')) : $html->submit('Submit Registration', array('name'=>'submit1b'));
echo $html->submit('Register Player using Registration Credits', array('name'=>'submit2', 'id'=>'submitregistrationusingcredits')); // this will use the credits of the team
```

Now on your coming page you can see if the first button was clicked with this code:

```
if ( isset($_REQUEST['submit1a']) ) ... // some code
// or, if the first button has the second possibility
if ( isset($_REQUEST['submit1b']) ) ... // some code
```

To see if the second button was clicked:

```
if ( isset($_REQUEST['submit2']) ) ... // some code
```